# What tag synonyms should be created?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Since the regular tag synonym suggestion mechanism is [essentially completely broken on this site](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/please-vote-on-tag-synonym-paste-cut-copy-paste#comment1336_1578), please post your tag synonym suggestions below.  One suggestion per answer, please.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker maybe lock or close this question as well?

Comment: As it turns out, the regular tag synonym suggestion mechanism is [essentially completely broken on this site](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/please-vote-on-tag-synonym-paste-cut-copy-paste#comment1336_1578). As Martin suggested in that thread, I think we need a centralised place for this, so nominating this question for re-opening. (Mods, if this is reopened, please could you also remove the [status-completed] tag?

Answer (score 5):

[navigation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navigation) → [cursor-movement](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cursor-movement) as suggested by OP [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19878419#19878419). Though I'm not sure how many synonyms we really need to create before people actually start using them.

Comment: AFAIK, no one re-created the navigation tag since it was renamed to cursor-movement ... It's also very ambiguous (file system navigation? window/buffer navigation? code layout navigation?) , so I'm not sure of creating a synonym is a good idea...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker agreed. No need for synonyms when no one tries to use a tag.

Comment: navigation has since been re-created, and now is used on 88 questions. The tag-wiki says it that's for navigating both within buffers but also between files and directories, so I guess it's actually a broader tag than cursor-movement. The two types of operation feel kind of distinct to me, but there are definitely questions tagged with *only* navigation that are about moving the cursor with a file, so possible we need cursor-movement to be a synonym of navigation?

Answer (score 4):

[yank](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yank) as a synonym for [cut-copy-paste](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cut-copy-paste)

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: Also [tag:kill] and [tag:put] perhaps (even though those don't exist yet), since those are the names in Vim. (In fact, I would think [tag:yank-kill-put] would be a better tag than [tag:cut-copy-paste], but I can't say how many people would agree.)

Comment: @Doorknob See the [discussion they had on Emacs](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/q/121) about copy-paste vs. kill-yank.

Answer (score 4):

All of the following should be made synonyms of [key-mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-mapping)

- [key-bindings](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-bindings)
- [remap](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remap)
- [noremap](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noremap)
- [nnoremap](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nnoremap)
- [vnoremap](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vnoremap)
- [xnoremap](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xnoremap)
- [snoremap](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snoremap)
- [onoremap](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onoremap)
- [inoremap](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inoremap)
- [lnoremap](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lnoremap)

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) For [key-binding](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-binding), but not for the others.

Comment: IMHO `key-mapping` or `key-mappings` would be slightly better, since this is the lingo that vi uses.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Edited for you

Comment: Don't create synonyms preemptively just out of a sense of completeness. A synonym [tag:key-bindings] → [tag:key-mapping] makes sense, but the litany of `*map` doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

[normal-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normal-mode) and [command-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-mode). They refer to the same thing. To make it more confusing, [command-line-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line-mode) in Vim is often just called "command mode"...

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: I hadn't been aware of the use of "command mode" to mean "normal mode" until just now. It is clear from [`:help modes`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-modes) that "normal mode" is the standard term. Also, Google shows 531k results for [_vi "normal mode"_](https://www.google.com/search?q=vi+%22normal+mode%22) vs. only 124k results for [_vi "command mode"_](https://www.google.com/search?q=vi+%22command+mode%22). I would consider "command mode" to be non-standard usage, and our tags should certainly discourage its use, especially given the confusion with [tag:command-line-mode].

Comment: @200_success Yes, but "Normal mode" seems to be Vim-speak. Look at the `nvi`
manual, and it doesn't mention "normal mode" at all ... There was already some
confusion where I "fixed" the insert-mode tag to change command-mode to
normal-mode, and someone changed it back... I agree this is rather
unfortunate...

Answer (score 3):

[split](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/split) and [window-management](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window-management) now mean the same.

I propose:

- [window-management](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window-management) for dealing with OS window management.
- [vim-windows](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-windows) for dealing with Vim windows.
- [split](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/split) can be an alias for [vim-windows](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-windows); I don't *really* see any value in keeping it as a separate tag.

Comment: I prefer [tag:split] as the master. "Window management" sounds a bit like something to do with the X11 window manager.

Comment: @200_success Hmm, there are also window management operations that do't really have to do with `:split`, as such (`:close`, `:help`, `:vertical`, etc.) ... Maybe `vim-windows`, or something like that?

Comment: [This question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/1937/24) is an example of the other kind of window management.

Comment: @200_success Yeah, good point. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Is [tag:vim-windows] excessively Vim-specific?

Comment: @200_success `vi` doesn't have the concept windows as we know it from vim. And if another vi clone supports windows, it's probably different than  Vim windows...

Answer (score 3):

[vimscript](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vimscript) and [viml](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viml)

`vimscript` is in use currently (probably taken from Stack Overflow, although there it's a synonym with `vim`), but `viml` is another name many may refer to the language. GitHub uses `VimL` also, which means many newer people to Vim would know by that name.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4398312/912144) as well.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Answer (score 2):

[write](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/write) as a synonym of [save](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/save)

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: Not sure on that one, you can write buffer to a different file, though save generally means save buffer to current file (unlike save-as, for example).

Answer (score 2):

[history](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) as a synonym of [forks-and-versions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forks-and-versions).  (The latter is preferred as the master because it is unambiguous, and would not be confused with the undo or command history features.)

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), in that everything seems to have been moved to [history-of](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of).

Comment: On the contrary, I prefer [tag:history] or [tag:history-of] as the main tag name, because I'd never think of using [tag:forks-and-versions] to mean this, and even seeing the tag name doesn't make it very clear that this is what it's about. “Forks and versions” feels like a made-up, undiscoverable name.

Comment: I agree with @Gilles that `forks-and-versions` is too obscure. `history-of` or `history-of-vi` would be better, and remove any confusion with command history.

Answer (score 1):

Among [external](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external), [external-command](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-command), [shell](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell), and [system-command](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-command), one of them needs to be the master. (Currently, it's [external-command](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-command), but that is negotiable.)

Comment: I would say `external-command` & `external` are synonyms (with the first being the better), but `shell` can also refer to questions about interacting vim with the shell (opposed to using `!`), so would consider that to be a separate tag.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker How about [tag:external-command] and [tag:invocation] then? And banish [tag:shell].

Comment: Fot this I prefer `external-command`.

Answer (score 0):

Recently asked a question regarding search and replace, and gave it the [search](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) and [replace](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replace) tags, funnily enough.

These were both deleted and replaced with [substitute](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substitute).

I can understand how `search` could be considered distinct since you can very much search without replacing or substituting.

But I can't see a distinction between `replace` and `substitute`, so I suspect one should be a synonym of the other.

This proposal is that [substitute](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substitute) should be the master one, based on little more than current usage levels (substitute = 6, replace = 2).

Comment: The distinction is explained in the tag wiki excerpt. [tag:replace] is what happens when you press `r` or `R` from Normal mode. [tag:substitute] is a regex-based change.

Comment: Apologies, @200_success, didn't see that since I'd only looked at the substitute one, which had no excerpt. Have added one to the review queue, you may want to have a look to see if it's suitable.

Comment: @200_success Isn't that called replace mode? (well, `R` is anyway); `replace-mode` would certainly making the distinction between the 2 tags clearer, and/or maybe `search-and-replace` can be a synonym for `substitute`?