# Please vote on tag synonym [paste] -> [cut-copy-paste]

Tags: discussion

The tag [`[paste]`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paste) is currently used on 26 questions, and has no guidance.

The tag [`[cut-copy-paste]`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cut-copy-paste) is currently used on 386 questions, and has the following guidance:

> Questions about cutting, copying, and pasting text. In Vim, "cut" is also called "delete", "copy" is also called "yank", and "paste" is also called "put".

Seems to me like `[cut-copy-paste]` is our canonical tag for this, so I've suggested `[paste]` be made into a synonym.

If you agree (or if you don't) [please vote](https://vi.stackexchange.com/tags/cut-copy-paste/synonyms)!

Comment: One thing I will point out is only people with a certain score in the tags can actually vote for it. If there is community consensus, but not the votes the mods can manually do it.

Comment: @Dom I didn't know either of those things were true. Thanks.

Comment: Voting for synonyms is basically broken on this site IMHO @Dom; the number of people who can vote is very small for many tags due to the requirements (need a score of 5 on the tag), and most won't see it because it's a pretty hidden feature. Mod approval is kind of the only way suggested synonyms will ever go through. I think almost all – if not all – current synonyms were created or approved by mods, rather than the community. Even for the no-brainer nvim → neovim one I had to [ping a mod](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/20803?m=56874825#56874825) after more than six months.

Comment: Maybe it's worth having a generic "tag synonym suggestions" question on meta that people can answer for suggested synonyms; that's a bit more obvious for mods to approve/disapprove, can have some discussion in the comments if need be (although most cases are pretty obvious), etc.

Comment: @MartinTournoij I'd be down for that and I know it's harder for smaller sites. Maybe we can also use the chat for a generic tag review first then formalize in a meta.